# Automation of web site testing at Chrome at android with device emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome, selenium, android-emulator, automation

Our company has quite a lot of automated tests for our web site for desktop for Chrome, IE and Firefox. Selenium WebDriver and C# used.

Now my task is to investigate possible solutions (shareware and free) for manual and automated tests at mobile browsers (apple and android) at different mobile devises *but without buying a devices.*

So I need to use emulators.

Whole day I investigated it and faced with some problems.

**Manual testing**

1. I found some android emulators for manual testing. Several are slow, other are faster but my problem is common. *What should I do if I need to have mobile chrome installed? I cannot install something inside to that emulators, can I?*
2. Does somebody knows the solution where I can test on devices manually in parallel?

**Automation testing**

1. Somebody tried to automate with selenium at mobile emulators?  I
   installed default emulator of android  (downloaded from here
   http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) but manually it is very
   very slow. It starts over 3 minutes and if I go to web site manually
   it takes more than 2 minutes (but sometimes 5 seconds) for each step
   in browser. Will it be the same automatically?